# How to use variables in an Unobtrusive Javascript onclick assignment?

Tags: javascript, unobtrusive

I'm trying to assign onclicks to td's in the first row, such that a click on the first TD outputs "1", a click on the second TD outputs "2", etc.

The problem is that when I actually click to call the onclick, I always get "3", because that was the last value of the variable that the onclick uses.

Is there a way to get each onclick to return the unique number I want?

```js
window.onload = function() { //Wait for the DOM to load.
    table = document.getElementById('myTable');
      for (i = 0; cell = table.rows[0].cells[i]; i++) {
        console.log(i); // logs 0, 1, 2
        cell.onclick=function(){ console.log(i);} // Want to get 0,1, or 2, but always get 3.
    }
}
```

```html
<table id=myTable>
    <tr>
        <td>COL1</td>
        <td>COL2</td>
        <td>COL3</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>one</td>
        <td>two</td>
        <td>three</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>four</td>
        <td>five</td>
        <td>six</td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That's because the `i` value is looking up to the nearest closure variable, if its not found, then it will be global. In your code it's global and mutated until the loop finishes.

Simply have `i` itself as a block-scoped variable

`for (let i = 0; cell = table.rows[0].cells[i]; i++) {`

Or assign it to another, in the following example, it's `idx`.

```html
<table id=myTable>
  <tr>
    <td>COL1</td>
    <td>COL2</td>
    <td>COL3</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>one</td>
    <td>two</td>
    <td>three</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>four</td>
    <td>five</td>
    <td>six</td>
  </tr>
</table>

<script>
  window.onload = function() { //Wait for the DOM to load.
    table = document.getElementById('myTable');
    for (i = 0; cell = table.rows[0].cells[i]; i++) {
      console.log(i); // logs 0, 1, 2
      let idx = i;
      cell.onclick = function() {
        console.log(idx);
      } // Want to get 0,1, or 2, but always get 3.
    }
  }
</script>
```

Comment: Why not `let i = 0;`?

Comment: @hev1 Anyway he sees fits. I will edit to provide with `let i`

Comment: Thank you.  Your code has the same problem as my code, but your explanation showed me how to fix it.  (Should be console.log(idx), not console.log(i).)

Comment: @MichaelBluejay Aha, I printed `i` instead of `idx`. Anyway, glad you got.